# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to find `9` raise to power `19` using numpy.

I am using `numpy 1.24.3`

This is the code I am trying:

```
import numpy as np
np.long(9**19)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sadly, `numpy.long` was deprecated in `numpy 1.20` and it is removed in `numpy 1.24`

If you wan the result you have to try `numpy.longlong`

```
import numpy as np
np.longlong(9**19)

#output
1350851717672992089
```

https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

Answer (score 1):

It should actually be `np.int_` as it is an [alias](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_) of `np.long` and would get you the same result as `np.longlong`, **particularly** in this case:

```
np.int_(9**19)

# prints
1350851717672992089
```

You can use `np.longlong` if your requirement is a 64-bit integer type.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an error in NumPy like `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'`, indicating that there is no `'long'` attribute in the `'numpy'` module, it may be due to the absence of the `'long'` type in the latest version of NumPy. To resolve this issue, you can roll back to a previous version(before version 1.23.0) using the following command:

```bash
pip install numpy==1.23.0
```

Now you can execute the code in your current Python environment after performing this installation.

Comment: Why the long winded explanation of the error? And the existing answer already explains it.

Comment: @gre_gor Because I believe this is a more convenient approach, it can reduce the modifications to the codebase to be replicated, and since the modified version is better suited to the original codebase, this can avoid more potential issues.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: And downgrade is a workaround, not a solution. Being stuck on the old version is not "a more convenient approach". And causes issues of newer (and probably better) features not being available.