# Error when running python machine learning model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to follow tutorial video and run [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/camenduru/PanoHead-colab/blob/main/PanoHead_custom_colab.ipynb#scrollTo=v9wpwlGfiX2e) on google colab.

After running second block of code, the following error is produced:

```
/content/3DDFA_V2/bfm/bfm.py:34: FutureWarning: In the future `np.long` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  self.keypoints = bfm.get('keypoints').astype(np.long)  # fix bug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/3DDFA_V2/recrop_images.py", line 322, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/content/3DDFA_V2/recrop_images.py", line 183, in main
    tddfa = TDDFA(gpu_mode=gpu_mode, **cfg)
  File "/content/3DDFA_V2/TDDFA.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.bfm = BFMModel(
  File "/content/3DDFA_V2/bfm/bfm.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.keypoints = bfm.get('keypoints').astype(np.long)  # fix bug
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 328, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'. Did you mean: 'log'?
cp: cannot stat '/content/3DDFA_V2/crop_samples/img/*': No such file or directory
```

update: have found more info about the particular error here:

[AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389395/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-long)

Would like to try to roll back `numpy` to previous version but not sure how to go about doing that in a colab like this.

Comment: The error is self explanatory:  `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'long'. Did you mean: 'log'?`  In this case you probably mean `int_` according to [this table](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: you're right, that part does seem pretty obvious, now that you mention it.. thanks for pointing it out to me.. I don't really have any experience with python or colab, but I'm going to make an effort to locate the source of "long" so that I can try changing it to "log"

Comment: btw, just found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389395/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-long

would like to try and roll back numpty but not sure how to go about doing that exactly

Answer (score 1):

The datatype `np.long` was [deprecated](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations) in NumPy `1.20` and removed from NumPy `1.24`. According to current [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_) for version `1.25`, you need to use `np.int_` instead.

In your case, go to `"/content/3DDFA_V2/bfm/bfm.py"` and replace line 34 with:

```
self.keypoints = bfm.get('keypoints').astype(np.int_)
```